# Give candidate name in web page title

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

When I [view a candidate](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/cv/1111), the title is "Employers - Stack Overflow Careers". I see this title at the top of the browser windows and in the task bar at the bottom of my screen, but it would be much more useful to see "Joe Coder - Stack Overflow Careers" instead, particularly when I have several windows open with different candidates in.

Comment: It's refreshing to see requests from an employer perspective

Comment: I wouldn't add the word `Careers` to the title though, that's what tags are for (I see you did it in all your questions)

Answer (score 3):

This is done...better late than never!