# "Unanswered" filter isn't as useful as it could be

Tags: discussion

As a new user, I'm scrolling through the "Unanswered" questions that I can help with and finding that most of them aren't questions.  They're informative posts... most with comments, but no "answers".

Perhaps there could be an option when posting a "question" to indicate that no "answer" is required.  Then the Unanswered filter could be made more useful.

Comment: Just to be clear... is this talking about a Meta site? Or are you seeing this on the actual Q&A sites?

Comment: I'm seeing it on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/, Unanswered tab/button.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Meta Stack Overflow work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work)

Comment: Basically, Meta Stack Overflow is... different.

Comment: I personally dislike "questions" like these, even on meta, and have been known to delete them if they are truly not questions. Do you have any specific examples?

Comment: As Saul mentioned, many of the "questions" seem to be bug reports, feature requests, etc.... things that may require discussion, but aren't really questions and don't require "answers". Check the Unanswered filter for examples, but here are the first 2 I see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40452 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38600

Answer (score 3):

The logic of things on Meta is a bit different when compared to the regular sites. For example, on Meta upvoting a question means "I like the idea" or "This issue deserves attention" in contrast to StackOverflow where you vote on correctness and relevance (at least most of the time).

People come here mainly to report bugs and discuss ideas, not necessarily to get answers per se. Among other things, Meta is also a way for users to communicate with each other publicly on various topics. It's not a regular Q&A site.

Besides, the traffic on Meta is low enough that if a question escapes the front page without yielding any answers, it tends to have a good reason.